# How to print a paper in Lua

Tags: printing, lua, coronasdk, love2d

I want to make a program in lua where I put the user puts several inputs and then press on a button and all these inputs are then printed in a certain format in a paper, How do I physically print a paper in lua ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a physical printer and sending it a file to print is fairly complicated and is beyond the scope of what I've done with Lua so far, but I would suggest checking out [this forum post](http://damnsmalllinux.org/static/act-ST/f-13/t-19941.html).

Your best option might be to save the stuff you want to print to a text file (such as a PDF using a Lua to PDF library, there are several available with a Google Search, such as [this one by cpressey](https://github.com/cpressey/pdf.lua) or [this one by jung-kurt](https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf)) and then using C++ or some other language to send that file to a physical printer and print it. Microsoft has a pretty decent [guide on how to do that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819270(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hopefully you find this helpful, have a great weekend!